# read csv contaning arabic and english in php

Tags: php, database, csv, fgetcsv

welcome

im trying to read csv file in php my file contain Arabic data

what charset must be use to show correct result ??

```
echo iconv("???????",'UTF-8',$data[$c]."\0");
```

Comment: Hi Ala'a , could you please show me sample of the file so i can help you

Comment: so.. did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Arabic is usually encoded as [`ISO8859-6`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6), so try:

```
echo iconv("ISO-8859-6",'UTF-8',$data[$c]."\0");
```

Check out [encoding check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520338/online-encoding-checker-tool) and [Determine and change file character encoding](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/determine-and-change-file-character-encoding/) for information on how to find which encoding.

As well, you have to make sure that you use UTF-8 everywhere, and that PHP is configure to handle UTF-8.

In the html, add the meta-tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And save it in UTF-8 format. here is [how to do that in notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad).

[Enable UTF-8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) in the `php.ini`:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

For a full manual check [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

If its not already UTF-8 then it will most likely being iso 8859-6.

But you can't be sure. To get sure you'll have to **know** the source encoding as it cannot be detected reliable.